# How to lookup map defined in yaml file in the Groovy script and assign to variable based input provided from Pipeline UI

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

How to pass map of variables from the yaml file to variable in the jenkins file or just print in the text file.

For Ex:

i have test.yaml file it contains:

```
processor-create:
{
service: true
ingress: true
path: /tmp/data
},
processo-update:
{
service: false
ingress: false
path: /tmp/data
}
```

i will provide input service_name: **processor-create** as a parameter from the pipeline and it has to go and look for that service in test.yaml, then whatever variables has "**processor-create**" it should assign to variable or print into another text file, so that i will pass that file as extra variable file for ansible script in the next stage, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure this is a valid yaml file ? 
to me the right syntax must be:

```
processo-update: 
    ingress: false
    path: /tmp/data
    service: false
processor-create: 
    ingress: true
    path: /tmp/data
    service: true
```

to parse the yml you can use snakeyaml, something similar to :

```
  @Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
  import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

  Yaml parser = new Yaml()

  map = parser.load( new File('text.yml').text )
  println map[args[0]]
```

read this post to a more elaborate example: https://groovy-lang.gitlab.io/101-scripts/basico/config_script-en.html

Comment: thanks for posting, i found an another issue while implementing above method in our jenkins pipeline

java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab

Comment: issue has been resolved, but right now am having an issue while storing "map" value into text file, it's printing in the console and am trying to assign value to env variable and through shell script printing into text file.
          env.map = map
         sh( """
           echo $map > "test.txt"
          """)

Comment: So if my answer solved your issue please vote it, please